# Debugging javascript running on the chromecast device

Tags: chromecast

I have my app working with some very basic receiver html however I would now like to do more on the receiver end. Is there a way for me to debug what is happening on the chromecast side? At this point I'm not even sure if my web page is getting refreshed each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your Chrome browser on port 9222 of your ChromeCast device: http://192.168.0.x:9222

By default the console tab will just show the current app's output, but if you jump from one app to another or your app receiver closes for some reason, you won't know why. To fix that, click on the settings icon (lower right corner) and enable "Preserve log upon navigation"

There appears to be a bug on the ChromeCast device where it caches older versions of the reciever. Just restart the device to force it to download the latest version.